# Ogmios: Follow the tutorial but the Server running for few seconds in Docker then auto terminate :?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Ogmios. I'm having trouble using it and I would like someone to help me please. My story is I'm following the tutorial, running [this command](https://ogmios.dev/getting-started/docker/#running) :

> docker run -it \
> --name cardano-node-ogmios 
> -p 1337:1337 
> -v cardano-node-ogmios-db:/db --platform linux/amd64 
> cardanosolutions/cardano-node-ogmios:latest

I add "--platform linux/amd64" to the command because the original command from the link produce error of not compatible between linux/amd64 (the images platform) and linux/arm64/v8 (my platform, I'm running on M1 mac).
The output of it is like this:

[image]

I guess the command run successfully, even though I don't understand what the last 2 lines mean.
**However, whenever I start the container in Docker, it only run a few seconds then stop**.
Here's the log of it in Docker:

[image]

I guess this should not be the behavior. I think the container is supposed to be running continuously so I can send API request to "localhost:1337" to get data from Cardano. Would anyone tell me what is the problem here please? Thank you!

Comment: you could check your system logs why those processes were killed, maybe out of memory. Or try running the docker again with as little as possible running in the background.

Comment: Hi @DaveStrider, I don't know what you mean about "system logs", all I can receive is the logs of docker, like this "/root/cardano-node-ogmios.sh: line 31:    14 Killed                  cardano-node run --topology /config/cardano-node/topology.json --database-path /db --port 3000 --host-addr 0.0.0.0 --config /config/cardano-node/config.json --socket-path /ipc/node.socket"
I don't know how to check memory exactly, I think my Mac M1 should not have this problem cause I only run this only one container and nothing in the background.

Comment: The docker container was build for Linux (with the ogmios binary compiled on Linux). It cannot work on Mac OS. The question was already answered on Discord, you will not get another answer by asking in different places.

Comment: @George-APEXStakePool yeah that's me asking, I ask here first but seem like no one answer so I move to discord.

Answer (score 0):

Did you got it running finally?
I'm having similar issues with running with docker the latest version, with the usual command
docker run -it 
--name cardano-node-ogmios 
-p 1337:1337 
-v cardano-node-ogmios-db:/db 
cardanosolutions/cardano-node-ogmios:latest

28 16:58:44.61 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: d46c975338e913e14abad59702c8d0dd5dabbe512fd744032e9490cdf70d5b16 at slot 22060401

/root/cardano-node-ogmios.sh: line 31:    11 Killed                  cardano-node run --topology /config/cardano-node/topology.json --database-path /db --port 3000 --host-addr 0.0.0.0 --config /config/cardano-node/config.json --socket-path /ipc/node.socket

That it will just die out randomly and afterwards restarting it will start syncing but it could randomly fail any time, maybe i need to add something  to add to that command that it will automatically restart when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of the issue, was that memory was running out( nothing was telling me about it... on closer inspection noticed it), i had to increase to maximal memory capacity through settings, if somebody will run in to the same problem.